# What is a 'parameter list' in the context of shell redirection?

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection

I found this statement while I was reading the POSIX documentation *Shell and Utilites* volume, section 2.1:

```
The shell performs redirection (see Redirection) and removes redirection operators and 
their operands from the parameter list.
```

Also, I found very similar statement from GNU bash reference manual, section 3.1.1:

```
Performs any necessary redirections (see Redirections) and removes the redirection 
operators and their operands from the argument list.
```

What is a "parameter list" or "argument list" here?

Comment: The word _parameter_ and _argument_ mean in this case the same, which is a bit unfortunate because bash also uses the word _parameter_ in the context of _PARAMETER EXPANSION_ (which is something different). Aside from this, those words are not specific to bash, but to programming in general. Take your favorite programming language: The things you pass to a function, are called _function parameters_ or _function arguments_. Since this can be considered a generally known term, I think the bash manual writers did not care to define it explicitly.

Comment: Also observe that when your write, i.e., a C program, you usually define the `main` function as `int main(int argc, char**argv)`. This _arg_ stands for _arguments_ and corresponds exactly to the use of the word _argument list_ in the GNU man page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that they're removed from the list of things that'll be passed to the command as arguments. For example, in this:

```
somecommand foo bar baz < inputfile.txt > output.log 2>&1
```

The redirects, `< inputfile.txt`, `> output.log`, and `2>&1`, get removed from the list of arguments, so it will execute `somecommand` with only three arguments: "foo", "bar", and "baz".

Note that this applies even if the redirects are mixed in with the arguments (or even if they're before the command!). So all of these are equivalent to the first example:

```
somecommand < inputfile.txt foo > output.log bar 2>&1 baz
somecommand < inputfile.txt > output.log 2>&1 foo bar baz
< inputfile.txt > output.log 2>&1 somecommand foo bar baz
```

(But the order within the argument argument list does matter, and so can the order of the redirects. In this case, putting `2>&1` before `> output.log` will change what gets redirected where, and probably not in the way you want. )

Comment: Thanks, but I'm just wondering, how did you know that? Is it mentioned somewhere? Or was it the only possible answer that you could think of? I also thought about this, but it seemed unnatural to me to say that redirection is an 'argument'.

Comment: @kjh6b6a68 *The shell performs redirection (see Redirection) and removes redirection operators and 
their operands from the parameter list.* is just an overgeneralized statement, not something to dwell on. How redirections are interpreted and performed, and how they interact with other constructs are documented in detail in following sections without using the ambiguous term *parameter list*.

Comment: @kjh6b6a68 The phrasing's a little klunky, but the meaning seems clear to me. The more detailed description in [section 2.9.1, "Simple Commands"](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01) is better: "2. The words *that are not variable assignments or redirections* shall be expanded. If any fields remain following their expansion, the first field shall be considered the command name and remaining fields are the arguments for the command."